# move inside shape - netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I need to implement the motion of small polygon shapes inside the world
The patches are colored this way:
1) big oval shape having blue color (appropriate patches are blue)

2) inside it 2  circular shapes having green color (appropriate patches are green)

Each circular shape "has" several tunnels turtles on its border
And I have several turtles having polygon shape, initially placed inside green circles(`polygonInside`)
I need the polygons motion inside circles until they hit one of tunnels. After that they go out and move inside oval only (not return to circle). I create appropriate `polygonOutside` instead of `polygonInside`
I tried:

```
ask polygonInside [
    let step  0.7
    ifelse (green = [pcolor] of patch-ahead 0.7)
    [
      rt random 90
      lt random 90
    ]
    [
      ifelse any? turtles with [ shape = "tunnel" ] in-radius 1.3
      [
        hatch-polygonOutside 1 
        [
          set shape "polygon"
          move-to min-one-of neighbors with [pcolor = blue] [distance myself]
        ]
        die
      ]
      [
        face min-one-of neighbors with [pcolor = green] [distance myself]
      ]
    ]
    fd step
  ]

  ask polygonOutside [
    ifelse ((blue = [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1))
    [
      rt random 90
      lt random 90
    ]
    [
        ; !!!!they are stucked 
        ; move-to min-one-of neighbors with [pcolor = blue] [distance myself]
        ; !!!!sometimes runtime error 
         face min-one-of neighbors with [pcolor = blue] [distance myself]
    ]
    fd 0.7
  ]
```

It almost works ok but there are 2 issues:
1) The polygons when they outside go very close to the green circles (almost intersect)
2)sometimes I get runtime error from

```
face min-one-of neighbors with [pcolor = blue] [distance myself]
```

Any advises how to solve them?